# What are the performance concerns of chaining multiple Array.prototype.*function*?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, time-complexity

Say I have a function `f` that iterates over an array of `n` elements to filter it with `k` conditions.

To improve readability I would be tempted to write it like so:

```
result = array
    .filter(predicate1)
    .filter(predicate2)
    .filter(predicate3)
    .filter(...)
```

Especially to avoid having to write things like this:

```
result = array.filter(e => test1(e) && test2(e) && test3(e) && ...)
```

Of course this above looks ok, but if I have multiple tests that hard to write nicely and it ends up being a mess of indentation... (please consider that)

Having `k` number of predicates. The complexity seems to be `O(k*n)`, right?

What are the performance risks if:

- there are lots of elements in the array (hypothetical lot, I'd actually appreciate your definition of lot)
- we execute the function `f` several times a second or even more
- other similar functions could be executed too

I have taken the case of filter because I just faced it, but the question holds for any chained method used when iterating arrays or other iterables.

#### EDIT:

In fact what I really want to know is the danger of using this kind of design globally.

Of course it is not going to be much of a concern on a single function. I am talking about the consequences on a complete application, where every similar case uses more iterations.

Comment: As you said it is bad to run over the array multiple times `O(k*n)` over `O(n)` and your suggested alternative has no side effects and doesn't look bad either, so just use it.

Comment: The only thing that gives it a small performance boost is, that the arrays *could* get smaller each iteration.

Comment: Using filter over and over will create arrays over and over which is bad for performance

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel - That won't improve performance over the `&&` version.

Answer (score 2):

The performance risk is simply that the time it takes to do repeated iterations (and/or to create and then reclaim those temporary arrays) instead of a single iteration creates a perceivable delay in your application, perhaps only on lower-capability hardware. The general advice is: Write what's clear and maintainable, and worry about a performance problem if/when you have a performance problem to worry about.

Whether you'll get one is impossible to say from the information in your question. You've said there are "lots" of entries in the array, but "lots" doesn't tell us much. :-) You've also said you'll be doing this processing several times a second, which does suggest that you'd be better off not unnecessarily looping through the array and creating intermediate arrays. But your mileage may vary.

If this comes up for you a lot, you might consider giving yourself some utility functions, such as:

```
function multiAndFilter(array, ...filters) {
    return array.filter(entry => filters.every(entry));
}
function multiOrFilter(array, ...filters) {
    return array.filter(entry => filters.some(entry));
}
```

...and so on, and then:

```
result = multiAndFilter(array, predicate1, predicate2, predicate3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain readability and mainatability by takeing an array for the predicate functions and iterate them as well.

Then take a single loop for fitering.

```
predicates = [test1, test2, test3];
result = array.filter(e => predicates.every(fn => fn(e)));
```